# FB does not allow using FB share dialog with Posting through Graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish-actions, fbsdksharedialog

Whe I am trying to get permission for publish_actions for my facebook app, it asks few points. One of those points is -

***My app does not use the Facebook Feed Dialog or the Facebook Share Dialog to publish content***

This means that If I want to get the publish_actions permission for using graph api to post on a user's wall I will have to remove all the FB share dialogs used in every place of my site.

After reading above I decided not to use publish_actions permission at all. But then I got a chance to look into change.org website. They are actually using both kynd of sharing. On the campaigns, they post to your wall via Facebook Graph API and on their blogs they are using facebook share dialog. So I am bit confused that can we use both simultaneously or not? And if not, how the change.org is able to do it?

Comment: you do not need publish_actions when using the share dialog, you only need it if you want to post with the api. if you just want to offer share possibilities, there is no need for publish_actions.

Comment: Yes, you can use both simultaneously. The quoted question might be a bit misleading/poorly phrased, but it’s purpose is just to filter out those apps that _only_ use the dialogs for sharing, and still try to get publish_actions approved. The permission is not needed for the Share dialog to work, and therefor there is usually no need to request it in such a case in the first place. If you have an app that uses the dialogs in other places, but for a specific piece of functionality needs the permission - then simply answer that question with “No” (resp., choose one of the other options.)